# How to get the URL of your EKS cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I've followed the steps to set up an EKS cluster and successfully have one service which exposes port 31515 from a pod..but I'm stuck at finding out what my public url is. EKS seems to have no such thing so how do I access it from the outside? Or am I not looking in the right place.

Answer (score 3):

Your all External IP's (Public IP's) should be available from `kubectl` Kubernetes command line.

To show these information run:

```
kubectl get services --all-namespaces -o wide
```

If it is needed specify with `--kubeconfig` flag your unique kubeconfig file.

Example:

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)    AGE
my-service   ClusterIP   10.3.245.137   104.198.205.71   8080/TCP   54s
```